# Mostrar toda la tabla en una tabla

Tags: php, html

Lo que quiero es que todo los registros de una tabla que se llama detalle_contratos se muestren en mi front y como yo lo tengo dentro de tablas llamo a la variable donde tengo el array de consulta pero solo me trae el primer dato.

```
                $ejecucion="SELECT * FROM detalle_contratos";

                                    $ar=mysqli_query($condb,$ejecucion);
                                    $flow=mysqli_fetch_array($ar);

                                    $nombreC=$flow['nombre'];   
                                    $fechaS=$flow['fecha_subida'];
                                    $fechaF=$flow['fecha_firma'];


                                ?>
                                <table class="table">
                                <th>
                                    Nombre 
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $nombreC ?></td></tr>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Fecha de subida 
                                    <tr><td><?php echo $fechaS ?></td></tr>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Fecha de Firma 
                                    <tr><td><?php echo $fechaF ?></td></tr>
                                </th>



                                </table>
```

Comment: hola, tienes que usar un ciclo para mostrar los datos ya que mysqli_fetch_array como dice hay en el nombre, te crea un arreglo de tu consulta, puedes usar un while o un foreach que yo personalmente mas uso. te dejo el link con el manual de esa funcion https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo te dicen en el comentario, lo que haces al traer la consulta y guardarla en una variable, es coger todos los registros de la tabla y volverlos un arreglo, con cada uno de sus campos, una forma de mostrar todos los datos sería así

```
                   $ejecucion="SELECT * FROM detalle_contratos";
                                    $datos = [];
                                    $ar=mysqli_query($condb,$ejecucion);
                                    while($flow=mysqli_fetch_array($ar)){
                                        $datos[] = $flow;
                                    }

                                ?>

                                <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                <th>Nombre<tr>
                                <th>Fecha subida<tr>
                                <th>Fecha firma<tr>
                                <tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                for($i=0; $i < count($datos); $i++){
                                echo "<tr><td>{$datos[$i]["nombre"]}</td>";
                                echo "<td>{$datos[$i]["fecha_subida"]}</td>
                                </th>";
                                echo "<td>{$datos[$i]["fecha_firma"]}</td>
                                </tr>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Lo que se hace es con el `count` traer la cantidad de posiciones que tiene el arreglo, y cada una de esas posiciones es una fila de la tabla, por lo tanto, se coge la variable `$i` (que es la que cuenta cada vez que sale del arreglo) para indicar la posición, entonces recorre cada uno de los registros e imprimes los campos que necesitas.
Inténtalo de esta forma, a ver que te parece, espero que te sirva, saludos!!

Comment: No dio error se que esta cerca del resultado satisfactorio, lo que no entiendo es por que me imprime '1'1'1'1, 'a'a'a'a''6'6'6' sin comillas si yo no tengo esos datos en mi tabla, y los demás me crea la tabla pero sin datos osea vacios

Comment: Haz ese cambio, la cosa es tambien que creo que el hecho como se está creando la, haz primero el encabezado `<tr><th>Nombre</th></tr><tr><th>fecha</th></tr>...`y después el contenido, sino que como lo estoy modificando directamente desde aquí es complicado acomodarlo

Comment: Ok, quito el error pero como el principio, solo me muestra la primera fila de la tabla

Comment: Listo, hice unos cambios en la tabla a ver

Comment: Dejando de lado que en vez de $row es $flow algunas comillas y algunos punto y coma todo funciona muy bien, gracias

Comment: Me alegra mucho, y sorry es que aveces me desvío y lo hago como tengo la costumbre de hacerlo xd, suerte con tu proyecto, saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer la prueba con este código.
Podría ayudarte de alguna manera.

```
<?php
$ejecucion="SELECT * FROM detalle_contratos";
$ar=mysqli_query($condb,$ejecucion);
?>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<th>Nombre<th>
<th>Fecha subida<th>
<th>Fecha firma<th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ar)){
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['fecha_subida'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['fecha_firma'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad y gracias por el apoyo, te recomiendo leer [answer], ayudaría mucho no solo a quien preguntó sino que además al resto de usuarios que consulten el que nos indiques que cambios hiciste y como este script soluciona el problema

Answer (score -1):

Con un `foreach` y recorriendo elemento por elemento

```
 foreach ($flow as $act)
  {
      echo $act['nombre'].$act['fecha_subida'].$act['fecha_firma'];
  }
```

Comment: Lo tengo así y no funciona, ya no necesitaria la tabla html o si